# Unable to concat trim function in string correctly

Tags: php

I have a string "Bengaluru's 1st Sign Language". I want to remove the apostrophes in this string using trim function in php. This string is named as heading variable in the below code for Read more.

```
function readMoreFunction($heading, $story_desc,$link,$targetFile,$id) 
{  
    //Number of characters to show  
    $chars = 512;  
    $story_desc = strip_tags($story_desc);
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  
  // Concatenation issue
  $story_desc = $story_desc." <a target='_blank' aria-label='Read More - 
  ".trim($heading, '"')."' href='".$link."/".$targetFile."/".$id."'>Read 
  More...</a>";  
    return $story_desc;  
}
```

Expected Result

```
 <a target='_blank' aria-label='Read More Bengalurus 1st Sign Language' href='https://yahoo.com/story/16558'>Read More</a>
```

Comment: What output you're getting when you don't use `trim`?

Comment: <a target="_blank" aria-label="Read More - Bengaluru" s="" 1st="" sign="" language="" href="https://yahoo.com/story/16558">Read More...</a>

Comment: Don't know why but I am getting the desired output with trim here.

Comment: _“Expected Result”_ - why? That would be _falsifying_ of the data you actually have there. You should properly _escape_ the `'`, not remove it

Comment: As per php manual, trim() is used to strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string.

Comment: @04FS Please suggest the right way how I can get the output with the apostrophe.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Why do you want to use `trim` for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the solution I found alright.

```
function readMoreFunction($heading, $story_desc,$link,$targetFile,$id) 
{  
    //Number of characters to show  
    $chars = 512;  
    $story_desc = strip_tags($story_desc);
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,$chars);  
    $story_desc = substr($story_desc,0,strrpos($story_desc,' '));  

    $ariaLabel = "Read More - ".htmlspecialchars($heading,ENT_QUOTES); 

    $story_desc = $story_desc." <a target='_blank' aria-label='".$ariaLabel."' href='".$link."/".$targetFile."/".$id."'>Read More...</a>";  
    return $story_desc;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$heading ="Read More Bengaluru's 1st Sign Language";
echo $goodUrl = str_replace("'", '', $heading);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code? I don't see where you are using `trim` as requested by the OP